# How do I increase the font size beyond "is-size-1"?

Tags: html, css, bulma

```
<h1 class="title is-size-1-desktop is-spaced is-size-2-tablet is-size-3-mobile has-text-centered has-text-primary has-text-weight-bold">Hello World</h1>
```

How do I increase the font size of that? I want it to say "Hello World" much bigger. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css:

```
h1.title {
    font-size: 50px; // or however big you want it
}
```

or inline

```
<h1 style="font-size: 50px;" class="title is-size-1-desktop is-spaced is-size-2-tablet is-size-3-mobile has-text-centered has-text-primary has-text-weight-bold">Hello World</h1>
```

ps:
If you use the first method make sure none of your other classes is overwriting the font-size you could add !important to it to make sure but this is not best practice (font-size: 50px !important;)

Comment: ```
h1.title {
    font-size: 300px;
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}
```
This is the only thing in my css file and still does not work for some reason.

Comment: yup that should work, if not inspect the element to see if the font-size is set by another class

Comment: Could you put !important behind it

Comment: !important h1.title {
    font-size: 300px;
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}
Like that?

Comment: no like this h1.title { font-size: 300px !important; font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif; }

Comment: No problem! glad i could help could you accept my answer? :)